# PLSQL Question: Update Salary of employee using Random value with procedure block

Tags: sql, database, plsql, sqlplus

so I am struggling on figuring out the issue with this code. I have to write a procedure to setSalaries(),where I need to be able to update the salary of the person (name passed as parameter) to a randomly generated value in a range (passed as a parameter), but I am getting errors. This is my code so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
     Create or Replace Procedure setEmpSalary(p_name in VARCHAR low in INTEGER, high in    INTEGER)
     As

     l_salary AlphaCoEmp.salary%type;


    BEGIN
           Select salary from AlphaCoEmp where name = p_name;
           l_salary = ROUND(dbms_random.value(low,high));
           update AlphaCoEmp
           set salary = l_salary


          commit;
      END;
     /
     show errors;
```

This is the example code from another problem that is similar, but it assigns a value to every person in table

```
    Create or Replace Procedure setSalaries(low in INTEGER, high in INTEGER)
    As
    Cursor Emp_cur IS
    Select * from AlphaCoEmp;
    -- Local variables
    l_emprec Emp_cur%rowtype;

    l_salary AlphaCoEmp.salary%type;

   BEGIN
      for l_emprec IN Emp_cur
      loop
         l_salary := ROUND(dbms_random.value(low,high));

         update AlphaCoEmp
         set salary = l_salary
         where name = l_emprec.name;

       END LOOP;
       commit;
      END;
    /
    show errors;
```

Comment: Remove the ```Select salary from AlphaCoEmp where name = p_name;```.  You cant select into nothing in a stored procedure,

Comment: @alexherm

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/42     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOW" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ) , @ % default character
         The symbol "," was substituted for "LOW" to continue.

8/21     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ;

8/57     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:

LINE/COL ERROR

Comment: Are you using Oracle or mySQL?  You're missing a comma in the parameter declaration in create procedure statement.  Does it work if you hard code the low and high values?

Comment: @alexherm im using oracle. let me try that out and ill get back to you.

Comment: @alexherm ok so I added the comma, and now I get this, Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> Errors for PROCEDURE SETEMPSALARY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/12     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/11     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
SQL> SQL>

Comment: You are also missing a semi colon at the end of the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter on the `update`.  The `select` is unnecessary:

```
       update AlphaCoEmp
           set salary = ROUND(dbms_random.value(low, high)
           where name = p_name;
```